# Fill color between two curves

Tags: matplotlib

I have drawn two figures from data. Now I want to fill color between these two curves. 
How to fill red/gray color between FIG1 & FIG2? Is it possible to write something between the two curves?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib

matplotlib.rc('text', usetex=True)
matplotlib.rcParams['text.latex.preamble']=[r"\usepackage{amsmath}"]




A1=[433,628 , 818 , 1033 ]
A=[]
for i in range(len(A1)):
    A.append(log(A1[i])/log(2))


B=[ 
 0.3831877729, 0.400606980300000 , 0.411592505900000 , 0.420391061500000 ,

 ]

C=[0.309248554900000 , 0.317584568100000 , 0.326892109500000 ,
0.328224407200000 ]

D=[433,628 , 818 , 1032 ]

D1=[]
for i in range(len(D)):
    D1.append(log(D[i])/log(2))



plt.figure(figsize=(10,4.75), dpi=100)
FIG1, =plt.plot(A, B,  color='b')
FIG2,=plt.plot(D1, C,  color='g')

plt.grid(True)
plt.savefig("figth.eps")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's [`plt.fill_between()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.fill_between.html) for a pair of curves, which share the same x-data.
In terms of graphical accuracy this true for your example, so you can test to simply add

```
plt.fill_between(A, B, C, color='grey')
```

to your script.

However, if you have two curves with significantly different x-values, you might have to resample one or both of them for this command.

[image]

---

Example, including a command for placing text and how to do some things more efficient and readable

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

A1 = [433, 628, 818, 1033]
A = np.log(A1) / np.log(2)


B = [0.3831877729, 0.400606980300000, 0.411592505900000, 0.420391061500000]

C = [0.309248554900000, 0.317584568100000, 0.326892109500000, 0.328224407200000]

D = [433, 628, 818, 1032]
D1 = np.log(D) / np.log(2)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4.75), dpi=100)
plt.plot(A, B, color='b')
plt.plot(D1, C, color='g')

plt.fill_between(A, B, C, color='grey') 

plt.text(9.4, .36, 'New idea', va='center', ha='center', size=24)

plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I am getting error. TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the
inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to
the casting rule ''safe''

Comment: Sorry, I simply copy-pasted your code, which was not able to run because `log` wasn't defined. So I added `from numpy import log` first, then ran your code successfully and simply called afterwards `plt.fill_between(A, B, C, color='grey')` - which resulted in the above plot.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to write something in gray color?

Comment: Yes, it is. What, where...? There are different commands for different purposes of adding text elements in matplotlib. (axes labels, titles, ticklabels, annotations, free text...)

Comment: I want to write inside gray color 'New idea'